# Mysql query resulting some null fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have to find all users and details of them but some users do not have extra details so returning NULL instead of empty string. how i can get it empty string directly from query. ( NULL should be replaced with s empty string.)

Comment: check for `coalesce()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `IFNULL()`

```
Select IFNULL(col_name,'') as col_name From table
```

> `IFNULL()` takes two expressions and if the first expression is not
>   NULL, it returns the first expression. Otherwise it returns the second
>   expression.

Comment: Select IFNULL(col_name,'') as col_name From table

Comment: use **as col_name** @ArP